# Resources for Learning to format SharePoint Online Lists with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

What resources would you recommend for someone needing to quickly learn to format SharePoint Online list items and views using JSON?

The individual is not a developer but has basic knowledge of some coding languages and is proficient with HTML and CSS.

Web searches on the topic have come up empty.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through below Microsoft official documentations and resources for learning SharePoint JSON formatting:

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)
2. [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)
3. [SharePoint JSON Formatting syntax reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference)
4. [Advanced SharePoint JSON formatting concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced)

You can refer to below GitHub repository for SharePoint JSON formatting samples related to column, view and form formatting:

1. [SharePoint List Column Formatting Samples](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples)
2. [SharePoint List View Formatting Samples](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples)
3. [SharePoint List Form Formatting Samples](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/form-samples)

---

As user looking for these resources is proficient with HTML and CSS, I would like to recommend you to try using **HTML To Formatter** tool which can help building a JSON formatter from a given HTML. You can even put in some CSS to get inline styles populated:

[HTML To Formatter tool](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/tools/html-formatter-generator/)

Comment: Many thanks. I found these previously, but they didn't provide a lot of guidance on building views from scratch or even modifying the default automatically generated code.  I wish I could find some tutorials where step by step guidance was provided. I've looked on Udemy for courses and found nothing. There are JSON courses but nothing specific to SharePoint. It would be great to find some sort of online course specifically for SharePoint formatting.

Comment: I don't think there are any courses on Udemy or PluralSight or LinkedIn learning, etc. specifically for SharePoint JSON formatting. However, you can find lot of videos by @theChrisKent on official YouTube channel of M365 community at: https://www.youtube.com/@Microsoft365Community

Answer (score 0):

Here are some which should be helpful.

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

[Advanced formatting concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-advanced)

[List Formatting Samples](https://pnp.github.io/List-Formatting/)

[Chris Kent's Blog - List Formatting](https://thechriskent.com/tag/list-formatting/)